# Keyboard scrolling the whole view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am getting an issue while working with the keyboard in SwiftUI. My textfield is the first view of ZStack and I have ignored the keyboard for it, but my view is still scrolling up. I want the view to remain as it is when the keyboard appears.
This is a sample code of example, which is also not working. Finding a solution to it will give me an idea to work on actual project code.

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
            
            ScrollView {
                  Color.red
                    .frame(height: 314)
    
                  TextField("Name:", text: $test)
    
                  Color.yellow
                    .frame(height: 314)
                }
                .padding()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
    }
 }
```

Thank you for the help!